# Comparing output from two greps

Tags: bash, awk, grep, comm

I have two C source files with lots of defines and I want to compare them to each other and filter out lines that do not match.
The grep (`grep NO_BCM_ include/soc/mcm/allenum.h | grep -v 56440`) output of the first file may look like:

```
...
...
# if !defined(NO_BCM_5675_A0)
# if !defined(NO_BCM_88660_A0)
# if !defined(NO_BCM_2801PM_A0)
...
...
```

where grep (`grep "define NO_BCM" include/sdk_custom_config.h`) of the second looks like:

```
...
...
#define NO_BCM_56260_B0
#define NO_BCM_5675_A0
#define NO_BCM_56160_A0
...
...
```

So now I want to find any type number in the braces above that are missing from the `#define` below. How do I best go about this?
Thank you

Comment: `diff file1 file2`

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `awk` logic with two process-substitution handlers for `grep`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$2]; next}!($2 in seen)' FS=" " <(grep "define NO_BCM" include/sdk_custom_config.h) FS="[()]" <(grep NO_BCM_ include/soc/mcm/allenum.h | grep -v 56440)
# if !defined(NO_BCM_88660_A0)
# if !defined(NO_BCM_2801PM_A0)
```

The idea is the commands within `<()` will execute and produce the output as needed. The usage of `FS` before the outputs are to ensure the common entity is parsed with a  proper-delimiter.

`FS="[()]"` is to capture `$2` as the unique field in second-group and `FS=" "` for the default whitespace de-limiting on first group.

The core logic of `awk` is identifying not repeating elements, i.e. `FNR==NR` parses the first group storing the unique entries in `$2` as a hash-map. Once all the lines are parsed, `!($2 in seen)` is executed on the second-group which means filter those lines whose `$2` from second-group is not present in the hash created.

Answer (score 4):

Use `comm` this way:

```
comm -23 <(grep NO_BCM_ include/soc/mcm/allenum.h | cut -f2 -d'(' | cut -f1 -d')' | sort) <(grep "define NO_BCM" include/sdk_custom_config.h | cut -f2 -d' ' | sort)
```

This would give tokens unique to `include/soc/mcm/allenum.h`.

Output:

```
NO_BCM_2801PM_A0
NO_BCM_88660_A0
```

If you want the full lines from that file, then you can use `fgrep`:

```
fgrep -f <(comm -23 <(grep NO_BCM_ include/soc/mcm/allenum.h | cut -f2 -d'(' | cut -f1 -d')' | sort) <(grep "define NO_BCM" include/sdk_custom_config.h | cut -f2 -d' ' | sort)) include/soc/mcm/allenum.h
```

Output:

```
# if !defined(NO_BCM_88660_A0)
# if !defined(NO_BCM_2801PM_A0)
```

---

About `comm`:

> NAME
>          comm - compare two sorted files line by line
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
> ```
>    With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to
> ```
>
> FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.
>
> ```
>    -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>    -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>    -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without the surrounding context from your sample input files and no expected output but it sounds like this is all you need:

```
awk '!/define.*NO_BCM_/{next} NR==FNR{defined[$2];next} !($2 in defined)' include/sdk_custom_config.h FS='[()]' include/soc/mcm/allenum.h
```

Comment: :+1 for grep independent , FS='[()]' is for specifying any single character in [] can be a space separator, right ?

Comment: what I meant was e.g  if a file has :(colon),  ,(comma), | (pipe)  characters and I want them all to be treated as field separator I then Can I specify FS as   FS=[:,|] ?

Comment: @user3369871 correct, a bracket expression can contain character lists as you described and/or character classes and/or character ranges and they match against any single character described by that bracket expression.